# 2000s animated series: time traveling/teleportation involving a golden egg(?)

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I've been looking for this for quite some time and I haven't been able to find much on it. As far as I can remember it's a western-style animated series.

The premise of the show is centered around this magical object/artifact, I vaguely remember it as a golden egg (but it could easily be like an amulet, locket, medallion, pendant or something kind of spherical) which is split into thirds. The main characters – three(?) children, possibly siblings have one third, the show's villain has the other third, and they are all trying to obtain the other missing third. From what I remember, that final piece keeps teleporting, I think through various periods in history, and by using their own pieces of the golden egg they are able to transport themselves to try chase after it.

As for random and probably pointless details, I think there's a greenhouse/forest which they return to at the end of each episode? There might be a some kind of book kept in that greenhouse which may be relevant to their travels? And there is like one scene I think where they're chasing after the 'piece' on a moving train?

It isn't:

- *Adventurers: Masters of Time*
- *Time Squad*
- *Horrible Histories* (the animated series)
- *Time Warp Trio*
- *Flint the Time Detective*.

I remember the art being fairly similar to *Liberty's Kids*, or *The Mummy* (animated series) and *Time Kid*.

Oh and I'm pretty sure this came out in the 2000s, but there's a chance that it aired slightly earlier, around the late 90s, but it almost definitely could not have been anything that first aired after 2011.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: This is a lot more information than we get in most story-id questions. What language was it in?

Comment: This sounds very similat to UK's HTV 1982 live action show "Into the Labyrinth"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Les Enfants de Toromiro* (*Children of Toromiro*), a French series aired in 2001.

From [this Youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjY6lcMFJmc&list=PLoQWPF6irTqaDZ5glOcpndk8ssur_SsEy&index=1), most of the translation courtesy of DeepL:

> It all began one day in the year 2000: **a group of young children, four brothers and sisters**, inadvertently discovered the hidden entrance to **an underground passage at the foot of a tree around which they were playing. This tree is called the Toromiro.** They decide to brave the danger and explore this dark and endless tunnel, but they soon realise that this place is inhabited. This is how they met the master of the place: the Laps. This strange and mysterious being endowed with magical powers teaches the children that he has come from France in the year 1000 to entrust them with a mission of the utmost importance: to put an end to the actions of the Laps' eternal enemies, the Avidhatti, who have sworn to control the world. **The Laps can use its super powers to send anyone through time and space.** And here come our young heroes embarked on a fabulous adventure. In order to achieve their goal, **they must find the pieces of a magic egg so that they don't fall into the hands of the terrible Avidhatti**, on which the success or failure of their mission depends.

Timestamped to the opening (French), which starts with the egg split in three pieces:

---

Found with the Google query `dessin animé oeuf d'or magique voyage temps` (`cartoon magical golden egg time travel`) which brought up [a similar story-ID question on a French site](https://forums.commentcamarche.net/forum/affich-15578301-recherche-dessin-anime-de-mon-enfance) (translated):

> It was the story of a family of 4 children, 2 girls and 2 boys I think... They were always moved in time and space in order to find magic eggs before another (bad) man found them. It was an old "wizard" who took them there and their parents obviously didn't suspect anything.

Comment: Well spotted. How did you know to check for French results?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I'm French. When IMDb search and English-language Google queries bring up nothing, chauvinism kicks in and screams _"you gotta try searching in French! If anything story-ID hunting has taught you the more niche a Western cartoon sounds, the more likely it's from France (or sometimes Poland). Get over your dislike of irrelevant French-language Google results and start searching!"_ ... And sometimes it works :-)

Comment: OH MY GOD YOU'RE ACTUALLY MY HERO. I HAVE SPENT YEARS LOOKING FOR THIS. I HAVE LOOKED FOR FRENCH CARTOONS AND NOT COME ACROSS THIS! (I also do not speak any french to be fair) I CANNOT THANK YOU ENOUGH!! THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: @PleaseHelpSomehow you're welcome, I hope you'll find an English dub/sub (or whatever other language you may speak)  somewhere! :)

Comment: Thanks haha, I've been looking but it seems like the only language it's available in is French :/ Alas, maybe I'll find it in English at some point. Either way I'm honestly just happy that this show exists and that my brain didn't just randomly make it up